# How to make a function for autoset

Tags: php

I'm not sure if it is possible or not but what I am looking for a way making auto "set" for mysql results.

```
function test(){
        $pDatabase = Database::getInstance();
        $site = new Template("sites.tpl");
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM sites';
        $result = $pDatabase->query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $site->set("id",$row['id']);
            $site->set("category",$row['category']);
            $site->set("name",$row['name']);
            $site->set("html",$row['html']);
            $site->set("css",$row['css']);
            $site->set("js",$row['js']);
            $site->set("php",$row['php']);
            $site->set("details",$row['details']);
            $site->set("link",$row['link']);
        }
        mysql_free_result($result); 
    }
```

Maybe there is a better way doing all that $site->set ? I mean my code looks way too big and pointless. Any other ways ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call `$site->set` on all key/value pairs in `$row`

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        $site->set($key,$value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to this...
Assuming your site->set function will always take the exact table column names.

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       foreach($row as $k=>$v){
          $site->set($k,$v);
       }
    }
```

You could also alter teh $site->set function and do the loop there. And then just do this...

```
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $site->set($row);
    }
```

And the function.  Just an outline.  Not really sure what you have going on in the actual function.   But this is just an idea

```
   function set($arrorkey, $value=null){

        // If passed value is an array, do this...             
        if(is_array($arrorkey)){

           foreach($arrorkey as $k=>$v){
             $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
             //Or database binding or whatever you're actually doing inside here

           }
       } else {
          // If passed value, is a column, and value pair...do this.
           $_SESSION[$arrorkey]=$value;
           //Or database binding or whatever you're actually doing inside here
           // This is just an example
       }

       return;

     }
```